# Why 0 devices, but not 1?

Tags: library, led-matrix

I have found a sketch in Wokwi where a MAX7219 LED matrix is used. The sketch subject is to display 0 using `<LedControl.h>`. I don't understand why it's nessesary to send 0 unlike 1 in fourth parameter in library-object initialization.

`LedControl(int dataPin, int clkPin, int csPin, int numDevices=1);`

It seems it should be 1 there, but the sketch isn't working in that way.

```cpp
#include <LedControl.h>

int DIN = 12;
int CS =  11;
int CLK = 10;
LedControl lc=LedControl(DIN,CLK,CS,0);

void setup(){
  lc.shutdown(0,false);       
  lc.setIntensity(0,15);      
}

void loop(){ 
  byte zero[8]= {0x00,0x1c,0x22,0x22,0x22,0x22,0x22,0x1c};
  printByte(zero);
}

void printByte(byte character []) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,character[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree 0 is not correct. [On this page](https://wayoda.github.io/LedControl/pages/software) it says: "The fourth argument to LedControl(dataPin,clockPin,csPin,numDevices) is the number of cascaded MAX72XX devices ... only values between 1..8 are allowed here.".  Please add a link to the source of your code. Perhaps there is an explanation there why 0 was chosen.

Comment: https://wokwi.com/projects/373210641309244417
Here is that project.
It's working with 1.

Answer (score 0):

On [this page](https://wayoda.github.io/LedControl/pages/software) it says: "The fourth argument to LedControl(dataPin,clockPin,csPin,numDevices) is the number of cascaded MAX72XX devices ... only values between 1..8 are allowed here.".

Examining the [LedControl source code at GITHUB](https://github.com/wayoda/LedControl/tree/f86a18493e9594d7b7198bf894f529a1c79d5802), we see in [file LedControl.cpp](https://github.com/wayoda/LedControl/blob/f86a18493e9594d7b7198bf894f529a1c79d5802/src/LedControl.cpp#L47) in function LedControl() code which checks for unexpected values for the number of MAX7219 LED Matrix devices used:

```
LedControl::LedControl(int dataPin, int clkPin, int csPin, int numDevices) {
...
  if(numDevices<=0 || numDevices>8 )
    numDevices=8;
```

We can see if the number is less than or equal to 0 or is greater than 8 the code defaults to 8 devices.  So when passing a 0 the code will detect an unexpected value and create 8 devices by default.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear.
Unfortunately, I don't understand why the project isn't working with 1 device.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the LedControl code.  Check for updated in your Arduino IDE.

Comment: The problem was when I put 1 device in initialization and then in shutdown, setIntensity, setRow also used 1. But there must be 0, because it's the address of the 1 device.
Thank you so much for help